# Xaml Poblemas con ScrollViewer UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

Scrollview en [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml), para crear las interfaces de las aplicaciones universales de windows 10 UWP, me encuentro con un problema con el `scrollviewer`, me corta el texto de un `textblock` y no funciona el scroll entero de la página, pero si defino un valor al `height` del `textblock` el scroll funciona perfecto.

```
<Page
    x:Class="AboutThisPattern.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AboutThisPattern"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" RequestedTheme="Light">
   <ScrollViewer Background="White">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RelativePanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF003D66" RequestedTheme="Dark">
                <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="45,20,219,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Square150x150Logo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="96" Height="96"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="App name" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1.0.0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </RelativePanel>
        <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Height="auto"
                       Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus viverra orci ut erat viverra, eu tempus lacus dictum. Sed vehicula euismod nulla, nec fermentum eros vulputate at. Morbi nec mauris quis augue pretium pulvinar eget vel ipsum. In suscipit nisl eu magna tempor suscipit. Vivamus eleifend imperdiet faucibus. Mauris imperdiet, nunc a elementum aliquam, mi risus tristique lectus, vitae ultricies tortor ligula vitae purus. Vestibulum laoreet a risus eget condimentum. Quisque faucibus, justo vitae dignissim semper, leo augue varius mi, ac maximus tortor magna in massa. Cras tincidunt elit vitae nibh maximus, a pretium nisl efficitur. Cras eros velit, dictum eu posuere vitae, tincidunt ac ipsum. Morbi maximus ultricies purus, sed maximus risus volutpat sed. Vestibulum euismod ante id diam lobortis egestas. Etiam at rutrum augue. Proin facilisis sagittis enim, a sodales nisi feugiat in. Fin de la nota!"
                       Margin="10,20,10,-120.667"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Si pongo eso en `textBlock1` no funciona `Height="auto"` pero si pongo `Height=700` se puede realizar scroll en toda la página, pero si lo volteo en horizontal se visualiza demasiado espacio en blanco. Como puedo ajustar automáticamente a la altura que necesita el `textblock` para mostrar su contenido?
O como solventarías ese diseño de interfaz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solventado, el problema residía en el valor del margin, que estaba en negativo, y se puede quitar el height="auto"

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus viverra orci ut erat viverra, eu tempus lacus dictum. Sed vehicula euismod nulla, nec fermentum eros vulputate at. Morbi nec mauris quis augue pretium pulvinar eget vel ipsum. In suscipit nisl eu magna tempor suscipit. Vivamus eleifend imperdiet faucibus. Mauris imperdiet, nunc a elementum aliquam, mi risus tristique lectus, vitae ultricies tortor ligula vitae purus. Vestibulum laoreet a risus eget condimentum. Quisque faucibus, justo vitae dignissim semper, leo augue varius mi, ac maximus tortor magna in massa. Cras tincidunt elit vitae nibh maximus, a pretium nisl efficitur. Cras eros velit, dictum eu posuere vitae, tincidunt ac ipsum. Morbi maximus ultricies purus, sed maximus risus volutpat sed. Vestibulum euismod ante id diam lobortis egestas. Etiam at rutrum augue. Proin facilisis sagittis enim, a sodales nisi feugiat in. Fin de la nota!"
           Margin="10,20,10,20"/>
```

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como correcta ;)